# Odd behavior of try/catch

Tags: c++, try-catch, stdmap

My question is this: why does the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        test[0] = "three";
        test[5] = "five";
        test2[3] = 5.55;
    }
    void foo(int j)
    {
        for(int i = j+1; i <= 7; ++i)
        {
            try
            {
                std::cout<<test.at(i)<<"\n";
            }
            catch(const std::out_of_range&)
            {
                try
                {
                    std::cout<<test2.at(i)<<"\n";
                }
                catch(const std::out_of_range&)
                {
                    throw i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    virtual void bar()
    {

    }
    std::map< int, float > test2;
    std::map<int, std::string> test;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        test3[6] = 15;
        test3[7] = 42;
        bar();
    }

    void bar()
    {
        int k = -1;
        label:
        try
        {
            foo(k);
        }
        catch(int i)
        {
            try
            {
                std::cout<<test3.at(i)<<"\n";
            }
            catch(const std::out_of_range&)
            {
                k = i;
                goto label;
            }
        }
    }

std::map<int, int> test3;
};
```

print

```
three
5.55
five
15
```

and not

```
three
5.55
five
15
42
```

?

What I'm trying to do is iterate over a number of maps containing different data types that can't be held in 1 container and this is what I came up with

Comment: The short answer is "because the program flow is twisted enough to melt my brain". I can't give a longer answer without melting my brain.

Comment: you posted a messy spaghetti code! a goto inside a catch statement which refer to the try block above... very esotic :) Compiler should have had an hard time compiling it. Obviously that's spaghetti code with meatballs (that's OOP code)

Comment: downvoters please provide an alternative or a reason why you downvoted

Comment: The only possible answer is "because that's what the code does". If you explain *why* you think it should print the expected output, we can try to figure out what's wrong with your assumptions.

Comment: I would suggest you start over with this question, stating what you are trying to do, and not post the code you have now... Don't post the try/catch mess...

Comment: @interjay: exactly right! a program always do what it must do. the correct question would be: why I cannot understand my own code?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: I already stated what I'm trying to do, iterating over 3+ maps containing different data types

Comment: I really, *really* hope this isn't meant to illustrate the workings of some piece of production code. Instead of asking why this code doesn't do what you expect, perhaps your time would be better spent rewriting it to do exactly what you expect, in some kind of **sane** manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that what you need is:

- You want to print all values contained in different maps over a certain range of keys.
- The maps have different types of values. Not all keys are present in all maps.
- A derived class may contain additional maps.

Instead of this convoluted exception+goto design, why not use a simpler design based on a virtual method for printing a specific value:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void showValue(int key) {
        if (map1.count(key))
            std::cout << map1[key];
        else if (map2.count(key))
            std::cout << map2[key];
    }

    void showAll() {
        for (int i=0; i<=7; i++)
            showValue(i);
    }

    std::map<int, float> map1;
    std::map<int, std::string> map2;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void showValue(int key) {
        if (map3.count(key))
            std::cout << map3[key];
        else
            A::showValue(key);
    }

    std::map<int, int> map3;
};
```

Comment: Thank you ! This looks like a much better way of doing it. Hope I can adapt it to my design

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that when you print 15, you `throw i`. This is not caught, and escapes up to:

```
   catch(int i)
    {
        try
        {
            std::cout<<test3.at(i)<<"\n";
        }
        catch(const std::out_of_range&)
        {
            k = i;
            goto label;
        }
    }
```

The number is correctly printed there, but won't restart. Without knowing more specifics, figuring out how to fix it is virtually impossible...

A much better solution would look something like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<=7;i++)
{
    if (test.find(i)!=std::map::end)
      std::cout<<test.at(i)<<"\n";
    else if (test2.find(i)!=std::map::end)
      std::cout<<test2.at(i)<<"\n";
    else if (test3.find(i)!=std::map::end)
      std::cout<<test3.at(i)<<"\n";
    else
      std::count<<"Nothing Found"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where the problem is although adding that goto creates an infinite loop.

Comment: See my edit, I think what you are really looking for it something close to what I've posted.